# Cannot convert type 'number' to type '0'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone help me understand and work around this error?

```
vehicleId = mapping.VehicleId;
```

This line is highlighted as red with the error

> Cannot convert type 'number' to type '0'

- vehicleId is type `number`
- mapping.VehicleId is type `number` [but is marked as optional]

---

As requested here is the exact way those variables / properties are defined:

In the function block:

```
let vehicleId = 0;
```

In mapping (note this is set via an HTTP request, not in code):

```
VehicleId?: number;
```

Comment: Add the part(s) of the code where you declare the types for `vehicleId` and `mapping.VehicleId`, and also where you assign a value to `mapping.VehicleId`

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thanks, updated the question

Comment: What version of typescript are you using ?

Comment: In Typescript each number value is also a type so you can type something to the type `0` and then the assignment will not be valid. For example `let p:0 = 0; let d: number  = 10; p = d;` will result in an error. But, at least in ts 2.5, when you write `let v = 0` v will get typed to number not to the type `0`. Do you think you could recreate a full minimal example ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Wow, specifying number actually works. Even though VS told me its type was number. Interesting. Please write this as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I had deleted the answer because I also checked in VS and it said number, and I thought I might be wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript each number value is also a type so when you write `let vehicleId = 0;` it will be typed to the type `0`. Then you cannot assign anything to the variable except something that has the same type (namely `0`). It is a bit confusing but there are uses for this. Try :

`let vehicleId:number = 0;`

or

```
let vehicleId = 0 as number;
```

Comment: *"when you write let vehicleId = 0; it will be typed to the type 0"* -- This is incorrect, `let vehicleId = 0` will always create a variable of type `number`, you can verify it in this [demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20value%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0Avalue%20%3D%202%3B). The issue is that somewhere, `vehicleId` is explicitly defined as `let vehicleId: 0`, which is not an assignment of the value `0`, but setting the type to a numeric literal (which, in this case, can be `0` only). This is most likely a typo from OP.

Comment: @JohnWeisz It's not a typo - I double checked. VS says it is a number but only after specifying its type as number does the error disappear.

Comment: @Chris what version of typescript are you using ?

Comment: @Chris Then I'm afraid something is incorrectly configured, or the issue is coming from elsewhere. You can verify in the demo that assigning any numeric literal to an implicitly typed variable will always create a `number` (except when doing some madness like `let a = 3 as 0`).

Comment: Version 2.2 is installed but I'm running 2.1 in my project